# issue with the newline print in python

Tags: python

I am new to python and I am having problem with the below code in assigning the i value

centriod_array is looks like below

[115 117 112 101 95 95 76 65 78 69 83 95 71 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 99 83 87 191 55 98 111 76

92 117 112 100 114 95 110 98 105 99 105 88 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 92 96 99 101 69 111 88 97

88 92 112 101 114 95 110 98 105  99 103 88 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 92 96 97 101 69 111 98 88
]

```
def get_tx (centriods,cnt,flag):
for i in centriods:
    if i == " ":
       cnt = cnt+1
       if (cnt == 30 and cnt <= 37) :
         tx = i
         print (tx)



  k=0
    while k < 3:
        get_tx (centriod_array[k],0,0)
        k = k+1


it is printing as below:

9
9 

8
3 

8
7 

1
9
1 

5
5 

9
8 

1
1
1 

7
6

....


>> i want it to be print like this 

99 83 87 191 55 98 111 76
92 96 99 101 69 111 88 97
92 96 97 101 69 111 98 88 



>> Basically i'm trying to print the values after "0".

Please help!!
```

Actually below is the exact element in array look like . Sorry for the confusion

```
'2 60 109 117 108 116 105 45 99 108 111 99 107 62 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 115 109 117 95 115 109 117 105 111 95 116 46 65 86 70 83 49 95 112 115 109 97 118 102 115 95 103 97 116 101 114 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 100 102 95 116 99 100 120 99 95 116 51 46 80 115 109 65 118 102 115 95 71 97 116 101 114 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 70 67 76 75 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0\n'
```

I want to extract the pieces and assign them to a variable like below:

```
60 109 117 108 116 105 45 99 108 111 99 107 62 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
115 109 117 95 115 109 117 105 111 95 116 46 65 86 70 83 49 95 112 115 109 97 118 102 115 95 103 97 116 101 114 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
100 102 95 116 99 100 120 99 95 116 51 46 80 115 109 65 118 102 115 95 71 97 116 101 114 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
70 67 76 75 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

other array which has non-zero to non-zero transition (here I've highlighted in bold)

```
'2 100 120 105 111 95 115 101 114 100 101 115 95 107 112 120 95 103 48 95 116 46 67 76 78 84 49 95 80 72 89 **48 95** 112 108 108 49 51 103 95 100 119 111 114 100 99 108 107 0 0 0 115 117 112 101 114 95 110 98 105 111 48 46 110 98 105 111 95 112 99 105 101 95 116 120 114 120 95 116 48 46 82 83 77 85 95 80 67 73 69 48 95 114 111 109 115 116 114 97 112 95 83 84 82 65 80 95 66 73 70 95 82 69 86 69 82 83 69 95 65 76 76 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 115 117 112 101 114 95 110 98 105 111 48 46 112 99 105 101 95 112 99 115 95 116 48 46 77 65 67 95 80 67 83 95 112 105 112 101 48 95 111 99 82 101 113 49 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 82 69 70 67 76 75 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0'
```

Please help!!

Comment: Please indent your code properly

Comment: `I am having problem with the below code in assigning the i value` how do you want `i` value to be assigned?

Comment: Can you show exactly how `centroid_array` is? Is it an array of strings or just integers?

Comment: Hi Austin, just integers (ascii) , like   ['115 117 112 101 95 95 76 65 78 69 83 95 71 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 99 83 87 191 55 98 111 76\n', '92 117 112 100 114 95 110 98 105 99 105 88 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 92 96 99 101 69 111 88 97\n', '88 92 112 101 114 95 110 98 105 99 103 88 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 92 96 97 101 69 111 98 88\n']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works as you desired; makes use of `rsplit` on each item in `centroid_array` to retrieve values after last `0`:

```
centroid_array = ['115 117 112 101 95 95 76 65 78 69 83 95 71 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 99 83 87 191 55 98 111 76', 
                  '92 117 112 100 114 95 110 98 105 99 105 88 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 92 96 99 101 69 111 88 97', 
                  '88 92 112 101 114 95 110 98 105 99 103 88 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 92 96 97 101 69 111 98 88']

for x in centroid_array:
    print(x.rsplit(' 0 ')[-1])

# 99 83 87 191 55 98 111 76
# 92 96 99 101 69 111 88 97                                          
# 92 96 97 101 69 111 98 88
```

As requested in comments, to retrieve numbers starting from 50th space to 200th space:

```
def get_tx(centriods):
    for i, x in enumerate(centriods.split()):
        if i >= 50 and i < 200:
            print(x, end=' ')

get_tx(s)
```

Or simply:

```
print(' '.join(s.split()[50:200]))
```

where, `s` is your input.

Comment: thank you.!! Actually i have updated the array .Sorry for the confusion.Can you please help.

Comment: The outputs for first example and second example are logically different. Do you mind explaining the logic you are talking about? As it stays, first and second are entirely different.

Comment: Yes.. i want to assign  pieces of the array element to variable after  it finds "0". means whenever "0" ends  from there till it finds next end of "0", i want those in between numbers to be stored in a variable. Please let me know if it  is not clear.

Comment: need all in-between values , pasting the array here  '2 60 ....  0  0 115 109 117 95 115 109 117 105 111 95 116 46 65 86 70 83 49 95 112 115 109 97 118 102 115 95 103 97 116 101 114 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 100 102 95 ... i need values in between 0  (before 115 )  and 100 (bottom)  like that

Comment: Any commnets pls?

Comment: From the last example output of your question, I assume you need a split (newline) on a transition from `0` to non-zero. Can you confirm if thats your need?

Comment: but there are cases like non-zero to non-zero transition as i mentioned in the main code now.

Comment: When I say `0` to non-zero, case is clear as one item is `0`. But when you say, non-zero to non-zero transition, which non-zero elements are you referring to? I see numerous non-zero to non-zero transitions. I see the bold part `48 95`. But on what **criteria**? There is another `48 95`. Sorry to say, no one can answer with details you provided. Read [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: sorry for that..by looking at the array element, there are spaces in between each and every ascii number.I want the chunk  from where  it reaches the 50 spaces (from beginning of the element)  to 200 spaces.this is the key criteria to split. we can try with this criteria for one chunk as of now.Please let me know if it is not clear

Comment: i can give you the clear picture of how this element is  represented .Its actually 401 length string  (<1char><50char><150char><150char><50char>) converted to ASCII. While converting each char (equivalent ASCII number)  is separated by space and that's what exactly you see the array element.The reason for adding zeros is that if the parts of the string length not matches with predefined length  then we appended the "0"s.

Comment: the format is like <type>:<clk>:<st>:<end>:<clk1>, assigned  predefined length as <type> is 1 bit constant number, <clk> is 50 length, <st> is 150 length,end is <150> length,<clk1> is 50 length.If any of the incoming data less than the predefined length , then we dded the "0"s to match length for each respective part.

Comment: "...I want the chunk  from where  it reaches the 50 spaces (from beginning of the element)  to 200 spaces..." Answering this, you can do `print(' '.join(s.split()[50:200]))` where `s` is your input.

Comment: Hi Alex,  def get_tx(centriods):
    for i, x in enumerate(centriods.split()):
        if i >= 50 and i < 200:
            print(x, end=' ')   ,                                                                                  
 > this printing  the each slice  in same line.Could you please help me , how to print each slice in next line ?                                                                                        > also, how to assign print (x, end='')   value to a variable  ??